# Token refresh mechanism javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, token, refresh, spotify

My application relies completely on API calls to Spotify.

Since it is client-side only it would not be safe for me to use the refresh token logic that Spotify suggests and therefore I am trying to implement a different mechanism, that consists in making the handleAuthorization call every time the token is about to expire, so that the user gets re-authenticated and gets a new token.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Route, Routes} from 'react-router-dom';
import LandingPage from './components/LandingPage';
import UserDashboard from './components/UserDashboard';
import PlaylistPage from './components/PlaylistPage';
import ConnectionError from './components/ConnectionError';
import 'react-notifications/lib/notifications.css';
import axios from 'axios';

function App() {
  const [token, setToken] = useState('');
  const [profile, setProfile] = useState({});
  const [playlists, setPlaylists] = useState([]);
  const [isOnline, setIsOnline] = useState(true);


  useEffect(() => {
    const handleOnlineStatusChange = () => {
      setIsOnline(window.navigator.onLine);
    };
  
    window.addEventListener('online', handleOnlineStatusChange);
    window.addEventListener('offline', handleOnlineStatusChange);
  
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('online', handleOnlineStatusChange);
      window.removeEventListener('offline', handleOnlineStatusChange);
    };
  }, []);
  


  
    const handleAuthorization = () => {
      const clientId = 'my-client-id';
      const redirectUri = 'http://localhost:3000';
      const scopes = ['user-library-read', 'playlist-read-private', 'playlist-modify-private', 'playlist-modify-public', 'playlist-read-collaborative'];
      const authorizationURL = `https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=${clientId}&response_type=token&redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent(
        redirectUri
      )}&scope=${scopes.join('%20')}`;
    
      // Redirect for authorization
      window.location.href = authorizationURL;
    };

    const fetchData = async () => {
      const hash = window.location.hash;
      const tokenParam = new URLSearchParams(hash.substring(1)).get('access_token');
  
      if (tokenParam) {
        // Token is present in the URL
        const newToken = tokenParam;
        window.localStorage.setItem('token', newToken);
        setToken(newToken);
  
        // Redirect to the dashboard
        window.location.href = '/dashboard';
      } else {
        // Token is not present in the URL, handle token expiration or other logic here
        const storedToken = window.localStorage.getItem('token');
  
        if (storedToken) {
          // Token is stored locally, you can set it and perform necessary actions
          setToken(storedToken);
  
          // Fetch user data and playlists here
          try {
            const response = await axios.get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/me', {
              headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${storedToken}`,
              },
            });
  
            const { data } = response;
            setProfile(data);
  
            // Fetch playlists
            try {
              const playlistsResponse = await axios.get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/playlists', {
                headers: {
                  Authorization: `Bearer ${storedToken}`,
                },
                params: {
                  limit: 50,
                },
              });
  
              const { data: playlistsData } = playlistsResponse;
              setPlaylists(playlistsData.items);
              console.log(playlistsData.items);
            } catch (error) {
              console.error('Error fetching playlists:', error);
            }
          } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching user data:', error);
          }
        }
      }
    };

    const checkTokenExpiration = () => {
      const storedToken = window.localStorage.getItem('token');
  
      if (storedToken) {
        const tokenData = JSON.parse(atob(storedToken.split('.')[1])); // Decode JWT payload
  
        // Calculate the remaining time before token expiration (in seconds)
        const currentTime = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
        const expirationTime = tokenData.exp;
        const timeToExpiration = expirationTime - currentTime;
  
        // Set a threshold (e.g., 300 seconds) for when to refresh the token
        const tokenRefreshThreshold = 300;
  
        if (timeToExpiration <= tokenRefreshThreshold) {
          // Token is about to expire, refresh it
          handleAuthorization();
        }
      }
    };
  
    useEffect(() => {
      // Check token expiration every minute
      const tokenExpirationCheckInterval = setInterval(() => {
        checkTokenExpiration();
        fetchData();
      }, 60000); // 60 seconds
  
      return () => {
        clearInterval(tokenExpirationCheckInterval);
      };
    }, []);
    


 
  const logout = () => {
    setToken('');
    setProfile({});
    setPlaylists([]);
    window.localStorage.removeItem('token');
    // Redirect the user to the home page after logging out
    window.location.assign('http://localhost:3000');
  };




  return (
    <div>
    {isOnline ? (
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<LandingPage handleAuthorization={handleAuthorization} />} />
        <Route path="/dashboard" element={<UserDashboard profile={profile} playlists={playlists} logout={logout} />} />
        <Route path="/playlist/:id" element={<PlaylistPage />} />
      </Routes>
    ) : (
      <ConnectionError />
    )}
  </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

for debugging reasons, i've set the timer to call the function every minute, but the code does not work and I get this error: "Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document'". How could I fix this?

Comment: does this error refer to a line of your code? You don't use `querySelector` anywhere in what you've posted, so, it's hard to do your debugging for you - looks like a typo somewhere (in code you haven't shown) using `Document.querySelector` rather than `document.querySelector`

Comment: @JaromandaX i checked my code but i haven't used Document.queryselector anywhere

Comment: what about `Document.querySelector`? something is doing that, since that's the error - have you checked the stack trace on the error to identify the line of code throwing the error?

Comment: the code that's generating the problem is this in main.js 

 /**
   * Easy selector helper function
   */
  const select = (el, all = false) => {
    el = el.trim()
    if (all) {
      return [...document.querySelectorAll(el)]
    } else {
      return document.querySelector(el)
    }
  }

it takes the token from the url and says it is not a valid selector.
'#access_token=my-token&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600' is not a valid selector.

Comment: interesting, it says `document.querySelector` not `Document.querySelector` - you sure about a) the error and b) where the error is thrown

Comment: @JaromandaX yes. 100%